# AddData tool stop working after Interoperability connection has been used?

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.0, development, arcgis-engine

Bug in ArcGIS Engine? Has anyone seen this behavior? We get an exception from our ArcGIS Engine test projects after we had been testing the Interoperability connection in ArcEditor.

We had to enable unmanaged code debuging in VS because the test application crashed without telling what happened, we get a stacktrace that look like this:

```
'TestMapWFSLayer.exe': Loaded 'C:\Test\TestMapWFSLayer\TestMapWFSLayer\bin\Debug
...
'TestMapWFSLayer.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rasadhlp.dll'
First-chance exception at 0x7680b727 in TestMapWFSLayer.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: FNPNS::TSM::CDoesNotExistException at memory location 0x003799c4..
...

'TestMapWFSLayer.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wship6.dll'
'TestMapWFSLayer.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WSHTCPIP.DLL'
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xd90) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0xfd8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
First-chance exception at 0x7680b727 in TestMapWFSLayer.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: FNPNS::TSM::CDoesNotExistException at memory location 0x00379974..
...
'TestMapWFSLayer.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\icmp.dll'
First-chance exception at 0x7680b727 in TestMapWFSLayer.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: FNPNS::TSM::CDoesNotExistException at memory location 0x00379f20..
First-chance exception at 0x7680b727 in TestMapWFSLayer.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: 
...
First-chance exception at 0x7680b727 in TestMapWFSLayer.exe: 0xE0000001: 0xe0000001.
... 

...
First-chance exception at 0x7680b727 in TestMapWFSLayer.exe: 0xE0000001: 0xe0000001.
...
...
'TestMapWFSLayer.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ESRI\Data Interoperability Extension\DIDatasource.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'TestMapWFSLayer.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Engine10.0\bin\fme.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'TestMapWFSLayer.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ESRI\Data Interoperability Extension\fme.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'TestMapWFSLayer.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wsock32.dll'
'TestMapWFSLayer.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ESRI\Data Interoperability Extension\xerces-c_2_8_fme.dll'
'TestMapWFSLayer.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ESRI\Data Interoperability Extension\icuuc38_fme.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'TestMapWFSLayer.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ESRI\Data Interoperability Extension\icudt38_fme.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'TestMapWFSLayer.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ESRI\Data Interoperability Extension\tcl_fme.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'TestMapWFSLayer.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ESRI\Data Interoperability Extension\threadlockmgr.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'TestMapWFSLayer.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shfolder.dll'
'TestMapWFSLayer.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.openmp_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4974_none_80bb23871e9ab973\vcomp90.dll'
'TestMapWFSLayer.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ESRI\Data Interoperability Extension\xerces-depdom_2_8_fme.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'TestMapWFSLayer.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ESRI\Data Interoperability Extension\icuin38_fme.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'TestMapWFSLayer.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ESRI\Data Interoperability Extension\fme_stringconverter.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'TestMapWFSLayer.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ESRI\Data Interoperability Extension\fme_sqlite3.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'TestMapWFSLayer.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\ESRI\Data Interoperability Extension\res\fmearcgisext_res.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
Critical error detected c0000374
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in TestMapWFSLayer.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in TestMapWFSLayer.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while TestMapWFSLayer.exe has focus.

The output window may have more diagnostic information.
```

Update: Tried uninstalling the Data Interoperability Extension (DIE):

When I tried using the AddData tool after uninstalling DIE, it was i bit slow but after a while it gor visible and I was able to use it.

Installed the DIE again and the AddData dialog workes until I hit the geodatabases tab.[image: AddData dialog]

Comment: Does it reach the license initialization code before crashing?  What licenses are you initializing?

Comment: @kirk-kuykendall I'm using the ESRI MapControl template to generate a test project (the same happens if I start any of my old projects as well) so it's only the standard binding and licenscontrol stuff in the project. I also tried adding AOInitialize in the form load to check-out a data interop license without any luck. Bottomline I should not have to use any extra licenses because I'm only using the standard AddData tool. I've also tried restarting the machine and changing profile...

Comment: Did you try turning off the data interop extension in arcmap, closing arcmap, then running your test app?

Comment: @kirk-kuykendall It is turned off, I also tried removing all intraoperability connections and closing ArcMap. But it is stuck in this state. I'm trying to follow the events leading up to the crash using process monitor but I can't find a file or registry entry causing the problem.

Comment: I get the same kind of crash if I open an MXD that has been saved with a WFS-connection.